# Laravel 5 search in a JSON file and show data

Tags: php, json, laravel, search, collections

I have a search engine with typeahead. What I want is that after doing a search and giving the submit, show the results. This gives two problems: first it **returns an empty array** and second, **it does not allow me to access the properties** telling me it is not an object.

**In controller,** I used collect() to allow me to access the properties, but it does not work and WHERE either.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $url = 'storage/json/es/noticia.json';
    $datos = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($datos, true);
    $data = collect($data)->where("title","LIKE","%{$request->texto}%")->all();

    return view('web.buscar.index', compact('data'));
}
```

If I use `$data = collect($data)->all();` I can see the collection:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => []
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "title" => "There is a title"
    "lead" => "There is a lead"
    "slug" => "there-is-a-title"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
  3 => array:4 [▶]
  4 => array:4 [▶]
  5 => array:4 [▶]
  6 => array:4 [▶]
  7 => array:4 [▶]

]
```

Then If I try: `$value->title` in the view I have the error: **Trying to get property 'title' of non-object**. In the **view** I have:

```
{!! Form::open([
    'route' => 'buscar',
    'id' => 'buscar',
    'name' => 'buscar',
    'class' => 'buscador col-xs-12',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'accept-charset' => 'utf-8'
    ]) !!}

    <input id="texto" name="texto" class="input_buscador typetitulo" autocomplete="off" type="text"/>

    {!! HTML::image('images/web/icons/lupa.svg', '',  array('height' => '30', 'class' => 'boton_buscador', 'onclick' => 'document.buscar.submit()') ) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

@if(isset($data))
    @foreach($data as $value)
        <span>{{$value->title}}</span><br>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

If I use `$data = collect($data)->pluck('title');` in the controller and in the view I don't call the property `'title'`, this works, but it's not what I want because I need to access other properties too.
Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your collection is an array, not an object, try `$value['title']` instead of `$value->title`

Comment: I don't really understand where did you get the `where` on collection is same as SQL `where`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where. Also code in one language only, look at how it looks when you mix two languages together (`$request->texto`).

Comment: your first value doesn't have anything so will fail on that

Comment: Oh! I've forgotten, if I use `$value['title']`I have the error: **Undefined index: title** Thanks anyway

Comment: if your on php 7 do `$value['title'] ?? ' '`

Comment: Yes @rchatburn , I'm in php 7, but like I said in this case I have the error Undefined index: title

Comment: In your dd your showing the first array with no values in it, so title will be undefined, if you do` {{$value['title'] ?? ' '  }}` it will do an isset and if its there echo it out ( which it wont for the fist one)

Comment: @rchatburn If I substitute `{$request->texto}` for `There` to test it, does not work either. Then I think that my first value it´s ok.

Comment: Oh! I understand @rchatburn I´m going to see why I have a first array with no value...

Comment: Thankyou! @rchatburn now It´s working.  I just have to solve how to do the where to the json file

Comment: Sorry, @Kyslik, I don´t understand what do you want to said me. How can I do a where in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because the first array in your array does not have any values, so you will get undefined index, remove any empty arrays by doing

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $url = 'storage/json/es/noticia.json';
    $datos = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($datos, true);

    $data = array_filter($data);

    $data = collect($data)->where("title","LIKE","%{$request->texto}%")->all();
    return view('web.buscar.index', compact('data'));
}
```

Or you can test to see if it is there in your foreach

```
 @foreach($data as $value)
    <span>{{$value->title ?? ''}}</span><br>
@endforeach
```

You can then search the collection using a filter

```
    collect($data)->filter(function ($item) use ($request) {
        return $item->title == $request->texto;
    )
```

You can edit the return to be more granular using stristr etc

Comment: Still I have a collection empty. It seems that `$data = collect($data)->where('title','LIKE',"%{$request->texto}%")->all();` It does not work.

Comment: try remove the { and change all to get?

Comment: If I use get() I have the error: **Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()** If I only remove the {} it´s the same result: an empty collection

Comment: Maybe I can not use LIKE in a collection, but there must be a way to do this

Comment: Confirmed. Laravel doesn't support where like in the collection.

Comment: Updated my answer to use a filter

Comment: Ok, this work fine: `$data = collect($data)->filter(function ($item) use ($request){
                return false !== stristr($item['title'], $request->texto);
            });` Thanks rchatburn!